# how to send image on UIIimageview to php server directly without storing image in iOS?

Tags: ios, image-uploading

i am new to iOS . now i am working in client's project. i need to upload image to php server. i select a image from simulator gallery and stored in simulator. then  tried to sent. but it shouldn't upload. how to send image without storing? please help me

Comment: how you select image and why you store image.

Comment: You should at least show your related codes.

Comment: i am using UIImagePickerController to select image. and i use xamarin.ios. please help me

Comment: how to send without  storing? any ways to send image from imageview?? please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert image to base64STring to upload on server,just do like this with your image:-

```
        UIImage *yourImage =info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSString *base64PhotoString;
    NSData *originalPhoto = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,.70);
base64PhotoString = [originalPhoto base64EncodedStringWithSeparateLines:NO];
```

and add this method:-

```
- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithSeparateLines:(BOOL)separateLines
{
size_t outputLength;
char *outputBuffer =
NewBase64Encode([self bytes], [self length], separateLines, &outputLength);

NSString *result =
[[NSString alloc]
  initWithBytes:outputBuffer
  length:outputLength
  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
free(outputBuffer);
return result;
}
```